# Sample rows of data for iteratively smaller samples

Tags: r, loops, iteration, sample

I have the following dataset:

```
group<- c(rep(1, 200), rep(2, 200), rep(3, 200), rep(4, 200), rep(5, 200), rep(6, 200)) 
injection<- c(rep(1, 200), rep(0, 600), rep(1, 400)) 
art_light<- c(rep(1, 400), rep(0, 600), rep(1, 200))
seasonal_light<- c(rep(1, 600), rep(0, 200), rep(1, 200),  rep(1, 200)) 

## generate data frame for species 1-3; where Species B is unaffected by all of these things and A and C are subtly different
## species is a random effect and so results are more generalizable
dat1 <- data.frame(group, injection,art_light,seasonal_light)
dat1$species = "A"
dat2 <- data.frame(group, injection,art_light,seasonal_light)
dat2$species = "B"
dat3 <- data.frame(group, injection,art_light,seasonal_light)
dat3$species = "C"

#################################
# Simulated Response  Variables #
#################################

alpha = 1
beta1 = 10
beta2 = 2
beta3 = 20
beta4 = 10

e1= rnorm(1200, 5, sd=1)
e2 = rlnorm(1200)
e = rcauchy(1200) 
e3 = floor(runif(1200, min = 0, max = 20))
e4 = rpois(1200, lambda = 4)
e5 = rlnorm(1200)

dat1$lh<-alpha + beta1*injection + beta2*art_light + 
beta3*seasonal_light + beta4*injection*seasonal_light + e1
dat1$hb<-alpha + beta1*injection + e2

dat2$lh<- e
dat2$hb<- alpha + beta3*injection + e3

dat3$lh<-alpha + beta1*injection + beta2*art_light + 
beta3*seasonal_light +e4
dat3$hb<-alpha + beta2*injection + e5
dat <- do.call("rbind", list(dat1, dat2, dat3))
```

I want to randomly sample rows within each `group` with no replacement. Sampling will be done iteratively such that in the first iteration of sampling, the number of rows sampled are the number of rows in `group` (n) and in the next iteration the number of sampled rows would be n-1.

These results should be combined into a data frame. Each subsample will be distinguished by a new variable `sample_num` that represents the number of rows sampled. Below is an example of the result data frame for the first 4 samples. The actual result should continue for all possible subsample sizes down to sampling of 10 rows.

```
samp1<-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  sample_n(size = 600)
samp1$sample_num<-600

samp2<-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  sample_n(size = 599)
samp2$sample_num<-599

samp3<-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  sample_n(size = 598)
samp3$sample_num<-598

samp4<-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  sample_n(size = 597)
samp4$sample_num<-597

samp_dat<- rbind(samp1,samp2,samp3,samp4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

res <- map_df(set_names(600:10),
              ~ dat %>%
                group_by(group) %>%
                sample_n(size = .x),
              .id = "sample_num")
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 1,081,530 x 8
# Groups:   group [6]
   sample_num group injection art_light seasonal_light species       lh    hb
   <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 600            1         1         1              1 B       -403.    38   
 2 600            1         1         1              1 A         49.3   12.5 
 3 600            1         1         1              1 B          0.961 31   
 4 600            1         1         1              1 A         48.7   12.1 
 5 600            1         1         1              1 B         -0.691 23   
 6 600            1         1         1              1 A         47.7   11.4 
 7 600            1         1         1              1 C         37      3.55
 8 600            1         1         1              1 B         -0.327 22   
 9 600            1         1         1              1 B         -7.71  32   
10 600            1         1         1              1 B          0.153 36   
# ... with 1,081,520 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

data.table is incredibly fast at this sort of thing

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(lapply(600:10, \(x) setDT(dat)[,.SD[sample(1:.N,x)], by=.(group)][,sample:=x]))
```

Output:

```
         group injection art_light seasonal_light species        lh        hb sample
      1:     1         1         1              1       C 35.000000  3.196606    600
      2:     1         1         1              1       A 46.424639 12.210558    600
      3:     1         1         1              1       C 33.000000  5.303823    600
      4:     1         1         1              1       A 47.316622 11.814838    600
      5:     1         1         1              1       C 39.000000  3.769120    600
     ---                                                                            
1081526:     6         1         1              1       A 47.249496 11.360076     10
1081527:     6         1         1              1       B -3.188948 29.000000     10
1081528:     6         1         1              1       A 47.263460 12.062339     10
1081529:     6         1         1              1       C 38.000000  3.307954     10
1081530:     6         1         1              1       B -2.760421 35.000000     10
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error: unexpected input in "rbindlist(lapply(600:10, \"

Comment: just replace `\(x)` with `function(x)`